# How can I install Ubuntu on a Compaq DC7900?

Tags: installation, bios

I have an HP Compaq dc7900 Convertible Minitower from 2006:

- 80GB (3.5”) SATA 3.0GB/s with NCQ and Smart IV
- Intel Core 2 Duo E8500

I can install Ubuntu on it from a USB stick and everything seems to work fine, but when I finish and reboot the pc, grub will be shown but When I continue I get just a black screen with a blinking cursor

I tried Linux Mint and OpenSuse as well but it seems there is something forbidden in the Bios.

Installing Windows 8 works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem with my HP DC7900 SFF with E8400 processor.
Download Ubuntu 13.10 64bit and write to USB stick. Boot PC from USB stick and install Ubuntu to Hard Drive.
Reboot PC and it freezes early in the boot process with black screen and flashing cursor.

I have managed to do the following to install Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit (haven't tried this yet with 64 bit, so still not sure exactly where the issue is):

Install Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit from a CD

Update using Software Updater via web to 12.04

Update using Software Updater via web to 12.10

Update using Software Updater via web to 13.04

Update using Software Updater via web to 13.10

Everything seems to work, but have not done many tests yet. Also it is only the 32 bit version. I hope to try installing the 64 bit version from CD tomorrow, possibly by repeating the above process to see at which point it fails (hopefully it will not fail).

---

Looks like the solution was much simpler:

Install Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit from a USB stick - fails to boot.

Install Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit from a DVD - works fine.

Looks like a problem installing 13.04 from USB. I used Universal USB Installer V1.9.4.4 to prepare the USB stick.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a me too comment.

Comment: @Elfy I think it is an answer. He got the latest version by upgrading from an older one.

Comment: @EricCarvalho "I am having the same problem" "so still not sure exactly where the issue is" is what I got from that post :) Perhaps it's just the way it's written - in which case Glenn should make it less ambiguous perhaps.

Comment: @Elfy I see your point... The first paragraph could be omitted, as it just restates the OP's issue. But I think knowing "exactly where the issue is" doesn't really matter because he got what he wanted after all (Ubuntu up and running on that hardware). And as the question doesn't mention 32- or 64-bit, I think this is a valid answer. Of course, a better answer would be one that describes how to directly install a supported version or one that explains why it can't be installed.

Comment: I think you have both made valid points about my post. I guess it is an answer if it helps lemba, or anyone else, get his system up and running. I intend to do some more tests and add information to this that I hope will help others. In the mean time if anyone else is able to do similar tests using the information I have posted then we may get to the answer quicker.